# how to increase number of "li" in this sample but maintain them in one row?

Tags: css, menuitem

how can i increase the `li` number for this menu(which contain 6 `li` by default) without jumping into new row. here is the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/DarkAge/cduzehbk/1/embedded/result/

when i add one `li` to the `html` file, the last "menu item" jump into new row.

how can i fix this?
 i tried changing `width` of `li`to 12%(which is 16.666666...% by default) and worked nice but as the `width` of `container` that contain menu to  is `960px` i got the menu not centered also there will be a "gap" on one side of menu.

Comment: You either increase your width from 960 to `li width * li number`, or you decrease your li width so that it `960 =< li width * li number`.

Comment: right! thanks.but i don't understand why -2 for my question? am i doing something wrong? i wish know so not make the mistake again(i am new here). and thanks for everyone who answered. :)

Comment: Stephan, don't take it personally. The community can be picky on what they consider good questions or bad questions. My guess is it was voted down because the answer seemed obvious. I did not vote down. Don't worry too much about it.

Comment: Yap. Thanks Mohamed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want 7 li on one row, just give them a width of 14.2857%. If you want n li on one row, you would give them a width of (100 / n)%.

Answer (score 0):

You have given width 16.6% which means whatever is the width of the container, it will always fix 6 menu item only. Change the width as 100/n where n is the number of li you want to appear in a line. In your case it would be 100/7=14.28%.

With this there will be no gap on the sides of the menu or if you increase the width of the container.